# KnockoutJS. Add data per drag and drop, when the binding data is empty

Tags: knockout.js, drag-and-drop

I have 2 Knockout sortables areas on my page like

```
    <div class="my_class" data-bind="sortable: { data: {my_data}">
       ...presentation of my_data
    </div>.
```

I can drag&drop from 1 area to another, what works fine, as far as my my_data is not empty. But as far as I emptied my first area by drugging all the data to the second I can't drug back from the second area into the first. How can I implement this behavior? Basically I need some  default drag & drop area when my_data is empty, so that I can drag back into it.
Thanks a lot for help
Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually I put a `min-height` on the `sortable` div, so that there is always some area to drop into.